# Angular Js popup with Yes No option

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller, popup

I am new to MVC and Angular JS need to create simple popup in angular js but unable to do so,

My view is like,

```
  <div id="Personal">
        <div class="portlet box green">
            <div class="portlet-title">
                <div class="caption">
                    {{ 'Cancelled Visits' | translate }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <!--  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">{{ 'VisitID' | translate }} </label>-->
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ 'Enter visit Ids comma separated' | translate }}" ng-model="ids">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

My controller is,

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('mysteryShopper');
    app.controller('MyVisitsController', MyVisitsController);

    MyVisitsController.$inject = ['$scope', 'utilitiesService', 'tasksService'];

    function MyVisitsController($scope, utilitiesService, tasksService) {
        $scope.pagesCount = 0;
        $scope.page = 0;
        $scope.pagesize = 10;
        $scope.path = utilitiesService.getFullPath();
        $scope.UpdateVisitStatus = UpdateVisitStatus;

        function UpdateVisitStatus (page) {
            if (page != undefined) {
                $scope.page = page;
            }

            tasksService.getVisitSummery($scope.ids).then(function (d) {
                var result = JSON.parse(d.data.data);
                $scope.data= result.result;
            });
           Here I want to code for popup with Yes No Condition

            var value = $scope.ids;
        }
})();
```

when i tried using this link http://www.javasavvy.com/angularjs-modal-window-tutorial/
 i got error while loading the required module step 3

Hopes for your suggestion 
thanks

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: HTML is not rendering properly when i add  MyVisitsController.$inject = ['ngTouch', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'] it shows me labels in this way  instead of Cancelled Visits it is showing {{ 'Cancelled Visits' | translate }} in all controls present in form

Comment: Check console log. You'll get error message. It would be a quick solution if you can provide us some  demo on https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: console error ui:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED